# Setting up Segment Registers, x86

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm, cpu-registers

I have a code:

```
[org 0x7c00]

CODE_SEG equ GDT_code - GDT_start
DATA_SEG equ GDT_data - GDT_start

cli
lgdt [GDT_descriptor]
mov eax, cr0
or eax, 1
mov cr0, eax
jmp CODE_SEG:start_protected_mode

jmp $
                                    
                                     
GDT_start:
    GDT_null:
        dd 0x0
        dd 0x0
    GDT_code:
        dw 0xffff
        dw 0x0
        db 0x0
        db 0b10011010
        db 0b11001111
        db 0x0
    GDT_data:
        dw 0xffff
        dw 0x0
        db 0x0
        db 0b10010010
        db 0b11001111
        db 0x0
GDT_end:

GDT_descriptor:
    dw GDT_end - GDT_start - 1
    dd GDT_start

[bits 32]

start_protected_mode:
    mov ax, DATA_SEG
    mov ds, ax
    mov es, ax
    mov al, "A"
    mov ah, 0x0f
    mov [0xb8000], ax
    jmp $

times 510-($-$$) db 0
dw 0xaa55
```

It works fine on qemu, but when I try to boot it on the real pc, it just reboots. I found in the Internet, that my problem is Segment Registers. How can I set them up, so the program could start working on real PC?

I've tried to set DS and ES to 0x07C0, but then program stopped working on qemu too.

Comment: Since you use `org 0x7c00` you want `ds` be zero when you do the `lgdt`.

Comment: See [General Tips for Bootloader Development](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32701854/boot-loader-doesnt-jump-to-kernel-code/32705076#32705076) and maybe [How to make the kernel for my bootloader?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33603842)

Answer (score 0):

First off, you have to set `ds` register to `zero` since you are set the origin address to `org 0x7c00`. This had been done by `qemu` and most probably with other virtual machines for you. But now during migrating to physical machine, you must take care of it yourself:

```
xor ax, ax
mov ds, ax
mov es, ax ; you may want this as well
```

Then, do not forget to set the `stack` with something like this or another area as you'd like:

```
mov ax, 0x9000
mov ss, ax
mov sp, 0xFC00 ; ss:sp (linear) -> 9FC00h (which is below BIOS area)
```

Comment: *since you are working below 64KB area of memory.* - No, the reason DS needs to be set to zero is to match `org 0x7c00`.  If they'd used `org 0`, setting DS to `07C0h` would be appropriate for accessing memory in their MBR loaded at linear address `7C00h`.  Setting SS:SP also seems unnecessary since they aren't writing any memory outside the 512-byte MBR, so there's no risk of clashing with wherever the BIOS put the initial stack pointer (which *is* somewhere valid.)  They're switching to protected mode so they could just set SS:ESP after that, if they have a stack segment in their GDT.

Comment: @PeterCordes I edited the answer by your recommendation. Concerning, ```ss:sp```, I wouldn't trust virtual machines for the same reason described for *ds*. But you are right, there is no memory usage outside of *MBR* region.

Comment: @MichaelPetch The `word [0:413h]` is actually the amount of KiB of base memory below the EBDA, not the size of the EBDA. So on a typical system with 640 KiB of RAM and a 1 KiB EBDA you will read the value 639 from this word. Shifting it to the left by 6 bits results in a segment address, then subtract something (eg 1000h corresponding to 64 KiB) to get a value for `ss`. You can adjust the `word [0:413h]` to reserve memory before loading another program, too.

Comment: @ecm, I must have been asleep when I wrote that. Thanks! I have spoken about that WORD before lol: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66577585/how-will-first-megabyte-memory-layout-be-changed-in-protected-mode#comment117696988_66577585